# parbox inner vertical-align "b" causes unexpected vertical white space

Tags: spacing, align, boxes, dimensions, parbox

In the following codes, I put something into a `lrbox` named `mybox`. Then the content of the box is typeset by a `parbox` with three inner vertical-align modes - `c`, `t` and `b`. For `t` and `c`, the typeset is alright. For `b`, an unexpected vertical white space occurs. Why? And how to correct it?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\parindent0pt

\begin{document}
\newbox{\mybox}
\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}\begin{minipage}{3in}
  aa\\bb\\cc\\dd
\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}

v-align=c: \fbox{\parbox[c][\dimexpr\ht\mybox+\dp\mybox][c]{3in}{\usebox\mybox}}\\
v-align=t: \fbox{\parbox[c][\dimexpr\ht\mybox+\dp\mybox][t]{3in}{\usebox\mybox}}\\
v-align=b: \fbox{\parbox[c][\dimexpr\ht\mybox+\dp\mybox][b]{3in}{\usebox\mybox}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Without understanding why, I observed that it looks as expected when you omit the 
depth from the height calculation in the third row: `\fbox{\parbox[c][\ht\mybox][b]{3in}{\usebox\mybox}`. Perhaps the experts can explain this.

Comment: @Heiko Theißen I need the total height of the box, that's the reason why `\dimexpr\ht\mybox+\dp\mybox` is used. This calculation is alright for `[c]` and `[t]` option, but introduces extra vertical white place with `[b]`, as show in my attached figure which confused me. You can see that with the same content in the same box under the same calculation, the height with different option gives different result. I had believed that they would have the same height.

Comment: On the other hand this works fine `\fbox{\parbox[c][\dimexpr\ht\mybox+\dp\mybox][b]{3in}{aa\\bb\\cc\\dd}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\minipage` gives an `\hbox(22.65277+17.65277)x216.81` that is almost as deep as high, because its contents are vertically centered with respect to the "math axis", which is slightly above the baseline.

Wrapping this in a `\parbox` with "top alignment" gives

```
\vbox(22.65277+17.65277)x216.81
.\hbox(22.65277+17.65277)x216.81
...
```

and "center alignment" gives

```
\vbox(22.65277+17.65277)x216.81
.\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
.\hbox(22.65277+17.65277)x216.81
...
.\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
```

But "bottom alignment" gives

```
\vbox(31.47916+26.47916)x216.81, glue set 17.65277fil
.\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
.\hbox(22.65277+17.65277)x216.81
...
```

which makes the `\vbox` higher and deeper than in the other cases. The desired height is `\dp\mybox = 17.65277pt` greater than the given height, and `\parbox` seems to add half the difference to each height and depth of the constructed box in this case.

This is just an analysis of the box dimensions, I do not know why `\parbox` behaves in this way.

But you can avoid the problem if you do not use `\minipage`:

```tex
\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}\vbox{\hsize=3in
  aa\\bb\\cc\\dd
}\end{lrbox}
```